# Attempting to create chance calculator

Tags: java, arrays, loops, random, int

I am relatively new to Java and wanted to try and make a code that would randomly generate 2 numbers a set amount of times, and it would track how many times the 2 numbers are the same. Then after X amount of attempts it would calculate the chance of it happening.

# of randoms divided by times they were the same

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] anArray;
    anArray = new int[100000];
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for (int loop = 1; loop < 1000; loop++) {
        int random1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
        int random2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
        if (random1 == random2) {
            int number = number + 1;
            countArray[number] = loop;
        }
        if (loop == 1000) {
            System.out.println("Took " + loop + " randoms.");
            break;
        }
        else {}
        }
    }
}
```

Main issue seems to be getting array to fill and to get ints in/out of the loop.

Comment: You'll find it a lot easier to follow your own code if you indent it more sensibly. Why do you have an empty `if` block? And when do you expect `loop` to ever be 1000 *within the loop*?

Comment: What do you need the array for? Is it for seeing how often the group of two numbers match ('54 22' matches with '54 22'), or how often the two numbers match ('22 22')?

Comment: Actually **loop** will never be 1000

Comment: You could use the `System.out.println("Took " + loop + " randoms.");` after the `for` loop, it would save you an empty `else` and the `if > break;` things

Comment: Array was to store loop number when the 'match' occured so an average could be calculated after the test ended.

Is intented properly on my end, messed it up with posting.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my version of your code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RandomTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> duplicates = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int random1 = 0, random2 = 0;
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        for (int loop = 1; loop <= 1000; loop++) {
            random1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
            random2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
            if (random1 == random2) {
                duplicates.add(new Integer(random1));
            }
        }

         for (Integer i : duplicates) {
             System.out.println("Duplicate: "+i.toString());
         }
    }
}
```

There are a number of problems that your solution contains:

```
int number = number + 1;
```

The above will create a new int called number and give it the value null + 1, this is because the above can be split into 2 lines:

```
int num;
num = num + 1;
```

The first line will reserve memory space for a variable called num. The second line will try and put the value of (num + 1) into num. As we are calling num and it has not been initialised - this will give us a java.lang.Error (at least that is what I got).

So as you can see, putting number outside the for loop and initialising it like this:

```
int number = 0;
for (int loop = 1; loop <= 1000; loop++) {
    number = number + 1;
}
```

Will increment the value of number by 1, 999 times.

Which brings me to the next point. The for loop will never make loop = 1000 because the condition will stop the loop before the condition is true, so when the for loop finishes, loop will equal 999. If you wanted the loop to finish on loop = 1000 you should use `loop <= 1000`. Also, the if condition is not necessary as when the loop finishes it will just carry on with the rest of the code beneath it.

I haven't used `number` at all in my solution, this is because I used an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which is essentially a much more advanced version of an array that can grow dynamically and do loads of other cool stuff. Unfortunately ArrayLists need to contain objects, so I wrap each `int` inside an `Integer` object and this is fine. At the end I use a for loop to iterate through the duplicates list, for each result I print it out.

Hope this helps and if you have any questions feel free to comment beneath.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is awesome.

Will be going through and reading up on all the stuff you mentioned.

Comment: If you liked my answer, please accept it as the official answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something about this line:

```
    int number = number + 1;
```

To step through the array, set number to zero

```
int number = 0;
```

before entering the loop then increment number with

```
number = number + 1;
```

Comment: While the bug is obvious for anyone who has done some (Java) programming, it might be more helpful for beginners if you would specify **what** should be done about that line. Superiority is uncool.

Comment: I was not trying to be superior, I was trying not to be patronising.  I assumed it was a typo, not a misunderstanding.